# Prove that $x^2=-1$ has no solution in $\mathbb Z$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have been asked to prove the following proposition:

Proposition 2.10: The equation $x^2=-1$ has no solution in $\mathbb Z$.

Our professor told us that we will need to prove for two cases, when $x=0$ and when $x \ne 0$.

My question is that I don't understand why we need to prove for two different cases. If anybody could shed some light that would be great.

Comment: It depends on what proof your professor has in mind. I wouldn't understand the need of two cases as well.

Comment: What alternate proof do you have in mind?

Comment: Maybe because the proof in mind involves dividing by $x$?

Comment: We have not yet 'learned' division so cant use it in our proofs.

Comment: It seems important to know what you *have* "learned"

Comment: @agra94 Can you prove that the only divisors of $-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ are $\pm 1\,$?

Comment: @AlexisOlson Hmm. That link is provides an example of exactly how our professor wants us to do this proof but it still doesn't really answer my question of why we need to solve for the two cases. The proposition that that person has us use is "let m∈Z. if m =/= 0, then m^2∈ℕ." Does this imply that we need the two cases because we need to know that m =/= 0?

Comment: Yes. The $0$ case is trivial though.

Comment: What definition/result do you have for multiplying negative numbers?